# Running multiple instances of an image with docker-compose fails

Tags: docker, playframework, playframework-2.0, docker-compose

Hi I am trying to deploy 4 docker containers containing the same image (which is a Java Play Application) and a Nginx which should loadbalance between those instances.

My `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  api1:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9000"
  api2:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9001"
  api3:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9002"
  api4:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9003"
  nginx:
    image: abfalterjakob/custom_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Running one of the api instances works fine, but whenever I am trying to run a second instance it crashes with this error:

```
Starting docker_api2_1
Attaching to docker_api2_1
api2_1   | tandard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" [recovered]
api2_1   |      panic: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
api2_1   |
api2_1   | goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
api2_1   | panic(0x7de000, 0xc82013efc0)
api2_1   |      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
api2_1   | github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction.func1(0xc82011f2e8)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:478 +0x38e
api2_1   | panic(0x7de000, 0xc82013efc0)
api2_1   |      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
api2_1   | github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization.func1(0xc82011ebf8, 0xc82001e038, 0xc82011ed08)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:259 +0x136
api2_1   | github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization(0xc8200d0f50, 0x7fa4847fc918, 0xc82013efc0)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:277 +0x5b1
api2_1   | main.glob.func8(0xc8200da3c0, 0x0, 0x0)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/main_unix.go:26 +0x68
api2_1   | reflect.Value.call(0x744b00, 0x8f0ed0, 0x13, 0x839c18, 0x4, 0xc82011f268, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
api2_1   |      /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:435 +0x120d
api2_1   | reflect.Value.Call(0x744b00, 0x8f0ed0, 0x13, 0xc82011f268, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
api2_1   |      /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:303 +0xb1
api2_1   | github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x744b00, 0x8f0ed0, 0xc8200da3c0, 0x0, 0x0)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:487 +0x2ee
api2_1   | github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x83cab8, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8d0420, 0x51, 0x0, ...)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/command.go:191 +0xfec
api2_1   | github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0xc820001680, 0xc820070060, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:240 +0xaa4
api2_1   | main.main()
api2_1   |      /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/main.go:137 +0xe24
docker_api2_1 exited with code 2
```

My guess is that this might be an issue with the ports?
Here the Dockerfile of the play application

```
FROM java:8

ADD target /app/target
ADD start_script.sh /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x ./start_script.sh
CMD ["./start_script.sh"]
EXPOSE 9000
```

Does anyone have an idea what the exact issue is here?

Comment: if you change EXPOSE 9000 to EXPOSE 9009, as there seems to be a conflict.

Comment: To clarify starting one of the api containers works, but as soons as I want start a second one I get the error

Comment: I changed your images to ubuntu, didn't see any error. Could it be that your base image has something to prevent it from running in two containers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You probably don't need to specify `ports`

If you don't need the ports on the API servers to be responsive *outside of Docker*, there is no need to specify `ports` at all. The `EXPOSE` statement in the image is already there. Your nginx container can already access port 9000 on each API container within the Docker network.

### You need to link the containers together so they can communicate

You do need to tell the nginx container to link to the others, though. Try something like this:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  api1:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
  api2:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
  api3:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
  api4:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
  nginx:
    image: abfalterjakob/custom_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - api1
      - api2
      - api3
      - api4
```

Now, your nginx container can communicate with the API servers using their service and port, e.g.

```
api1:9000
api2:9000
api3:9000
api4:9000
```

This has the additional benefit that your API servers are network-isolated from the outside, which improves security.

Again, this assumes the API servers should not be publicly accessible, but should be routed only via the nginx proxy.

### If you do map ports to the outside, you have to map internal to external

You are telling Docker to use ports 9000, 9001, and so on, but your image is set to only EXPOSE 9000. To map them to the outside, you need to set the external port and then map it to the internal port, like this:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  api1:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  api2:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
  api3:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
  api4:
    tty: true
    image: abfalterjakob/play-api
    ports:
      - "9003:9000"
  nginx:
    image: abfalterjakob/custom_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - api1
      - api2
      - api3
      - api4
```

In your original example, you used only a single port. That tells docker-compose to use that container port, but arrange a random host port. If you had told each of them to use port 9000, it would have bound port 9000 in each container to a random host port. But you specified non-exposed container ports in 3 of the 4 cases.

See the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports) for more.

Comment: Thanks!
Managed to work everything out. There was an additional problem with my current image which was the actual cause of the error message

Comment: As far as the documentation is writing about you do not need to link the containers to each other, using compose version x>=2. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/